# mysql - count total entries for two variables

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
select county, count(county) as total_entry from house
group by county;
```

I get

```
county   | total_entry
'county1'| '1'
'county2'| '11'
'county3'| '2'
```

Now I want to get below result :

```
county   | ad_type     | total_entries 
'county1'| SALE        | '1'      
'county2'| SALE        | '4'      
'county2'| RENT        | '5'      
'county2'| NEWHOUSING  | '2'      
'county3'| RENT        | '2'
```

How do I achieve this ? (ad_type is a field in house table).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this: (I'm assuming that your sum numbers are off because you want to group by ad_type as well)

```sql
SELECT county, COUNT(county) AS counties, ad_type FROM house
GROUP BY county, ad_type
```

Comment: thx!! works!! just realize group by works with comma, not with '&'.